# PC does not start with video card

Tags: power-supply, post

It's really strange situation that i cant't figure out.

Motherboard: ASRock G41M-GS3, Inter Core 2 DUO 2.13GHz, new PSU (Xilence 480W).
Problems start when i try to put in it my Radeon HD3850 - PC starts and shuts down in couple of seconds (POST does not complete). The interval between startup and shutdown is random, sometimes its less than second, sometimes 4-5. If i didn't power off the supply, it keeps trying to power up endlessly.

If i put the card in another computer, it works fine. If i put low-end video card (GeForce EN7300GS) in that new PC, it also power-ups fine.

I tried to power up only with video card (without HDD and optical drives), no change.

Comment: have you connected both cards to the same slot when trying? is the PSU providing enough Watts for the hardware?

Comment: Yes i use PCIEx slot for both cards. As i checked on the internet, the minimum power requirements for the HD3850 is 450W

Comment: Are you sure you plugged the required 6-pin PCIe power cable into the graphics card?

Comment: that is, 450W for the card, but take into account the rest of the hardware and peripherals depending on the PSU power. probably you should try using another one with higher Watts just for troubleshooting.

Comment: It sounds like the PSU isn't powerful enough to power your system.

Comment: Yes i plugged in the video card power connector also. AFAIK, 450W is required when fully loaded, but doesn't it should at least power up even when all other devices are not connected?

Comment: @Ramhound & @Znau, unlikely. The 450W spec is for the entire system, not for the card itself. If you look at the specsheet, it recomends a PSU with a "75 Watt 6-pin PCI Express® power connector" suggesting that the card will not draw more than 75W. 480W should be fine, assuming he actually plugged in the PCIe power connecter (something that the `GeForce EN7300GS` lacks).

Comment: @Rain - The PC is not even getting passed POST that itself indicates a power issue.

Comment: The HD3850 draws about 15W at idle and about 65W peak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was the PSU. I put the 400W PSU from my second PC into new with HD3850, it got trough POST imediately, and new PSU also works with second PC (and that has more powerful video card, HD6870). Never heard that PSU may be incompatible with MB/PSU.